# Какую технологию лучше использовать для передачи данных между сервером и android/ios в режиме реального времени?

Tags: android, ios, websocket, socket.io, realtime

Какую технологию лучше использовать для передачи данных 
 между сервером (spring-boot) и android/ios в режиме реального времен: socket, websocket, socketio, long-polling, etc.. ?

Comment: Ещё всякие *MQ  посмотрите. Зависит от того какие это данные и насколько важна оперативность доставки.

Comment: текстовые данные